# How do I search a CVS repository for a particular file?

Tags: version-control, cvs

Is there any way to do it? I only have client access and no access to the server. Is there a command I've missed or some software that I can install locally that can connect and find a file by filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could grep the output of

```
cvs rlog -Nh .
```

(note the period character at the end - this effectively means: the whole repository).

That should give you info about the whole shebang including removed files and files added on branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 cvs rls -Rde <modulename>
```

which will give you all files in  recursively, e.g.

```
foo:
/x.py/1.2/Mon Dec  1 23:33:51 2008//
/y.py/1.1/Mon Dec  1 23:33:31 2008//
D/bar////

foo/bar:
/xxx/1.1/Mon Dec  1 23:36:38 2008//
```

Notice that the -d option gives you also deleted files; not sure whether you 
wanted that. Without -e, it only gives you the file names.

Comment: isn't rls a CVSNT-only command?
also note that by default this will only report files that exist in (or have been removed from) HEAD. files added on branches (and not merged back) will not be reported by this.

Comment: ah, must be relatively new then - I'm pretty sure it wasn't there in CVS 1.11.x